# Why : Error Minted package with rule color?

Tags: errors, minted

I have problem about use minted package, my mwe like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Rub}{HTML}{061089}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[frame=lines,rulecolor=Rub]{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

After i use **rulecolor =red** and others color, i get like this :

[image: error]

How to solve it ?

Comment: The optional argument is in the wrong place: `\begin{minted}[...]`

Comment: @JosephWright Thank for your comment but i replace my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You need to put the optional argument in the right place, and slightly oddly the value of `rulecolor` is apparently a command not a colour name

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\begin{document}

%\tracingall
\begin{minted}[rulecolor=\color{red},frame=lines]{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```